# The definite article + adjective + noun

Tags: definite-article

> The given excerpt clearly shows the key features of the characters - **the**  furious father with mind clouded by the alcohol, **the** defenceless and unhappy mother and Elly, and **the** scared, but unbroken narrator.

All the characters were mentioned before, so should the definite article be used?

Answer (score 1):

When you say "the father", it just means there was one father.  How many times the father was mentioned before does not play a part in whether you say "the" or "a".

Comment: A correction like the now deleted one has no part in an answer. Submit an edit if you find such an error in the exposition of the question which has no bearing on the question itself, or leave a comment.